# Same view with multiple URL patterns and optional arguments

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am trying to design URLconf file, where one of the views accepts two optional parameters: `date` and `account_uuid`.

`views.py`:

```
@login_required
def dashboard(request, date=None, account_uuid=None):
    # some unrelated code...
```

`urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    'app.views',
    url(r'^dashboard$',
        'dashboard',
        name='dashboard'),
    #WHAT HERE??
)
```

user may visit url which contains one OR both parameters.

**Without arguments:**

> http://example.com/dashboard

**With date (ddmmyyy format) only should look like:**

> http://example.com/dashboard/01042015

**With account UUID only:**

> http://example.com/dashboard/e1c0b81e-2332-4e5d-bc0a-895bd0dbd658

**Both date and account uuid:**

> http://example.com/dashboard/01042015/e1c0b81e-2332-4e5d-bc0a-895bd0dbd658

How should I design my URLconf? It should be easly readable and fast.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using multiple patterns is probably the easiest way to achieve this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('app.views',
    url(r'^dashboard$', 'dashboard', name='dashboard'),
    url(r'^dashboard/(?P<date>[\d]{8})/$', 'dashboard', name='dashboard'),
    url(r'^dashboard/(?P<account_uid>[\da-zA-Z-]{36})/$', 'dashboard', name='dashboard'),
    url(r'^dashboard/(?P<date>[\d]{8})/(?P<account_uid>[\da-z-]{36})/$', 'dashboard', name='dashboard'),
)
```

Comment: The question is,is this correct? by correct meaning a good practice?